# How to solve mixed date formats

Tags: vba, date, excel

I'm trying to write VBA code in Excel 2010 to make some time calculations. Everything is working as I want BUT for the cell date format. The Excel Sheets were created by merging several .xlsx files generated by different PCs and a Hardware Data-logger. The problem is that some sheets had the date as `mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss AM/PM` and others `dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss AM/PM`, with both mixed in one file.

I tried to change everything to `Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy hh:mm;@"` but some cells just don't change. I also tried this function:

```
Function Arreglar_Fecha()
    Dim temp As String
    temp = ""
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
       temp = ActiveCell.Value
       ActiveCell.Value = Day(temp) & "/" & Month(temp) & "/" & Year(temp) & " " & Hour(temp) & ":" & Minute(temp)
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Function
```

But still, some cells changed, some did not. And what is worse, some get the day and month mixed!

[image: http://i.imgur.com/5yGEyzi.png]

[image]

I have access to some of the original .xlsx files and in there also wasn't able to change all the date formats.

Anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

**EDIT**  Here I got permission for put an original Excel file [Excel Data](https://db.tt/tcmo5bzX).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ActiveCell.Value = Day(temp) & "/" & Month(temp) & "/" & Year(temp) & " " & Hour(temp) & ":" & Minute(temp)

Maybe the code is reading it as text? Try this (UNTESTED)

```
Sub Arreglar_Fecha()
    Dim temp As String, Tmp As String
    Dim D As String, M As String, Y As String
    Dim H As String, Mn As String

    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
       temp = Trim(ActiveCell.Value)

       D = Trim(Split(temp, "/")(0))
       M = Trim(Split(temp, "/")(1))

       Tmp = Trim(Split(temp, "/")(2))

       Y = Trim(Split(Tmp, " ")(0))

       Tmp = Trim(Split(Tmp, " ")(1))

       H = Trim(Split(Tmp, ":")(0))
       Mn = Trim(Split(Tmp, ":")(1))

       ActiveCell.Value = Format(DateSerial(Val(Y), Val(M), Val(D)) & _
                          " " & TimeSerial(Val(H), Val(Mn), 0), _
                          "dd/mm/yy hh:mm;@")

       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Trying it with a single test scenario works. The below gives you `13/08/13 05:31`

```
Sub Test()
    Dim temp As String, Tmp As String
    Dim D As String, M As String, Y As String
    Dim H As String, Mn As String

    temp = "13/8/2013 5:31"

    D = Trim(Split(temp, "/")(0))
    M = Trim(Split(temp, "/")(1))

    Tmp = Trim(Split(temp, "/")(2))

    Y = Trim(Split(Tmp, " ")(0))

    Tmp = Trim(Split(Tmp, " ")(1))

    H = Trim(Split(Tmp, ":")(0))
    Mn = Trim(Split(Tmp, ":")(1))

    Debug.Print Format(DateSerial(Val(Y), Val(M), Val(D)) & _
                " " & TimeSerial(Val(H), Val(Mn), 0), _
                "dd/mm/yy hh:mm;@")
End Sub
```

Comment: First to all thansk @Siddharth . I edited my question adding your code in a loop that I'm using in this original file [link](https://db.tt/tcmo5bzX) (I got permission for put it public). Pretty much works but Had two problems, when (for some reason) one cell have the correct format, the macro gives an "9" error. Not big deal there, can be even manually fixed buy changing the active cell manually; BUT the other is that AM/PM times are getting changed to 24Hs wrongly, for example, if the time is 5:01PM is transformed to 5:01 Hours, and should be 17:01.

Comment: The sample data that you have in the file is slightly different. We will have to cater to AM/PM as well.

Comment: Ok, I find the solution, I added just after `H = Trim(Split(Tmp, ":")(0))` this code so add 12 to the hour value contained: `If InStrRev(ActiveCell, "p.m") <> 0 Then H = H + 12` . Now I just need to catch the exception (I don't know if this is possible in VBA) or just skip it manually and I will be able to merge correctly the data!

Comment: Are you referring to the first cell which doesn't have AM/PM?

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of those in the files, so Excel throws an "9" error when find some of those.

Comment: Simply use `INSTR()` to check for the delimiters before you use `Split` on them and then amend the code accordingly and everything will be fine :)

Comment: Yeap! you got it, I was trying that just now :) But weird enough, in that file that I uploaded, When I run the vba code something weird happen in from cell A750 to A809, I had: `09/19/13 12:00:00 p.m.` and it's converted to `09/07/2014 31/12/1899` I think it's because 12+12 it's 24 and 24 doesn't exist, should be "0". So I guess another IF is needed. `If H = 24 Then H = 0`

Answer (score 3):

You will have to trace back to your source data. There is no way Excel itself knows whether 1/2/2014 for example should be the first of February or the second of January, only that it is either 41671 or 41641.

*Edit* In your second example, clearly `28/9/2013 17:59` is September 28. If `10/01/13 12:11:00 PM` had the same formatting (perhaps came from the same file) then it is January 10. But if the formatting was different then it could be October 1. If you are seeing AMs and PMs with formatting as `dd/mm/yy hh:mm;@` then some of your data is text and there is no reliable 'automatic' way to switch this to a date/time serial number without knowing the text convention (ie whether DMY or MDY), hence the need to revert to source.

Obviously 'day' values greater than 12 are actually months but that does not help much when for less than 13 it depends upon the formatting.

In addition, given your various sources, there is a risk that both the 1900 and the 1904 conventions might have been used and even possibly others also (your data logger might be on UNIX time, which starts in 1970).

Comment: + 1 Technically you are right. Excel can not know. But if the user forcibly wants to convert to a specific format by splitting then that is possible :)

Comment: +1 @pnuts you have a point. That was my gut reaction, too, when I read the question. "Does the OP REALLY know which date is supposed to be DD-MM-YYYY versus MM-DD-YYYY if they only see the date and the first two items are both less than 13. It would not surprise me if the OP comes back to redact. But +1 to Sid, too for his approach.

Comment: @pnuts, thing is, once the data is inside Excel, Excel will have done its thing on interpreting it and has made up its mind about DMY or MDY.  Much easier would be to import the data with the wizard and **TELL** Excel if the dates are DMY or MYD.

Comment: `The Excel Sheets that I had, was created merging several xlsx files generated by different PCs and a Hardware Data-logger.` It all boils down to how the data was stored in the original file and finally how the merger took place. :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. PC "one" uses NZ settings with DD/MM/YYYY. PC "two" uses US settings with MM/DD/YYYY. Both PCs have Excel data with dates. I open the files with PC "three" and the settings are "whatever". Excel will show the dates with the PC "three" system settings, unless the dates have been hard-formatted to be something else. As long as the dates are real dates, PC "three" can just open the file and set the cell formats to "short date" and all will be hunky dory, no? What am I  missing here?

Comment: Ingeborg, Do you know what are the two things that I learned from you during my stint at ExpertsExchange way back in 2010? :) One is mentioned [here](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/08/01/to-err-is-human/) and the 2nd thing is "Never assume how a particular user is going to use Excel". Now when I said `it boils down to how the data is stored...`, I was referring to the 2nd thing that I learned. Users can be unpredictable. How can one ensure that the user entered the dates in DD/MM/YYYY format only and not in MM/DD/YYYY format in one of the workbboks? Contd...

Comment: Contd... It is very much possible that the user entered data in mixed formats in one of the file. The solution to the problem IMHO is to standardize a common method to accept dates across all workbooks and then merge them keeping that format in mind.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, how can I NOT luv ya after you are passing that quote back to me? And, of course, I totally agree that users don't necessarily enter data into Excel to promote easy processing. I **so** wish users would all learn how to operate the tools they are using every day and make their lives easier. Spend five minutes on learning a few basics every day and remove **hours** and **days** of time wasted on troubleshooting.  - I think this conversation should move to Meta.

Comment: @pnuts, yes, I think we need to cater for all kinds of users, even those who talk into their iPhone and expect perfectly formatted data in Excel.

Comment: @pnuts, I asked this question years ago in another forum: http://www.excelforum.com/the-water-cooler/726214-i-need-a-macro-to-do-this.html  -- most folks involved in the discussion are now MS MVPs, but were not at the time.

Comment: pnuts I do know the dates because those are correlative (thank god) but there's so much data! I asked to my wife and I will be able to have all the original ones(this is a favor to her). The thing is that the original doesn't have the correct format either, and can't be changed unless I edit cell by cell. The code that @Siddharth wrote are pretty close to the fix. I will need to rebuild and merge the finals sheets. BTW I agree that the users should know how to use the tools that they need! But redo this original sheets it's almost impossible, the data-loggers are in a far FAR away location.